# how do I query data from a user profile since getProfile() is removed?

Tags: django, django-models

My understanding is that since Django 1.5, Custom User Models are possible but not neccesary. In fact, Greenfeld and Roy argue in "Two Scoops of Django" that sometimes (like for creating a third party package) "Profile" models are still the way to go.
Since getProfile() has been removed however, I don't know how to target my Profile data in template. Because:

```
{{ request.user.get_profile.id }}
```

no longer produces any data, I've tried:

```
{{ request.user.userprofile.id }}
```

but that doesn't produce a value either.

So my question is, given the following model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(ClientList, blank=False, null=True, db_column='client', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    egroup = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EMP_GROUP_CHOICES)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=130, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    extension = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    hphone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()

    User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])


    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.fullname

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['fullname']

    class Admin: 
        pass
```

how do I get the userprofile.id in the template?

(note: not really relevant but the user object still explicity uses a foreign key in order to preserve the "on_delete" parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store user profile, it is recommended to use `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`. Although they are the equivalent.

Once you set the relation to `OneToOneField`, you can retrieve the userprofile id by using the following query: `user.userprofile.id`

If you decide to use `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`, you can still retrieve it using the following queryset: `user.userprofile_set.first()`

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: `first()` queryset is introduce in Django 1.6 and above. for Django 1.5 and below use the following query: `user.userprofile_set.all()[0]`